# How to convert from pptx to html

Tags: java, powerpoint

I have an ooxml file that contain the notes section from a pptx slide (extracted using POI).
Is there a way (framework, software) to convert it to html and still keep the original design (Bold, italic...)
of the notes.

Edit:
Never mind i developed my own pptx notes to html parser.

Answer (score 0):

I have used JODConverter library to convert openoffice ppt to html before.

http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it and it doesn't work. I don't know if it's because it doesn't support pptx2html conversion or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is alibrary called [docx4java](http://www.docx4java.org/) that has the capability to extract MS XML formatted files (docx, xlsx, pptx). Check it and check the sample SvgExporter on http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/convert/out/svginhtml/.

I used this library and it worked well in extracting the DOCX format as HTML or PDF.

Comment: I tried it already, the docx4java can only convert docx to html. the pptx to svg doesn't display the notes only the slide.